# How do I get posts that does not have any comment from a specific user

Tags: mysql

I have two tables **posts** and **comments** I want get all posts that does not have any comment from specific user_id.
Posts table have **id**, **title** and **content** field while comments table have **id**, **post_id**, **user_id** and **comment** field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use LEFT JOIN on both tables and the not equal comparison operator in the WHERE clause.

```
SELECT DISTINCT posts.id
FROM posts
LEFT JOIN comments
ON posts.id = comments.post_id
WHERE comments.user_id <> 123
```

Comment: Please add some explanation. The answer is flagged as low-quality.